# How to set DateTimePicker in worksheet column with closedxml.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datetimepicker, closedxml

I have used the closedxml.dll for generating worksheet.

I have an application where on click of button saves some data in **Excel** using **C#**.I have used the memorystream for saving inside the excel sheet. I have also kept dropdown for some columns inside sheet. When i download the excel and check the Data and the dropdowns are working fine.

Now I have a requirement like Calendar control should come for one column when I click on the cell like just in below pic situation.

[image: Excel]

Here when the cell on the column DOB is clicked Calendar or DateTimepicker should show to select the date.

Your help is high appreciable

Thanks

Comment: ClosedXML doesn't support form controls.

Comment: @FrancoisBotha Can you suggest any other rather than CloseXML which supports those things.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Place the ActiveX Control on the Worksheet.

- In the Controls section of the Developer tab click the Insert button
  to display a selection of controls.
- Click the More Controls button to open the More Controls dialog.
- Scroll down the list and find **Microsoft Date and Time Picker** Control.
- Click on the worksheet approximately where you want the control to appear
- use the mouse to resize and position it.
- Click the Design Mode button on the Developer tab to take the worksheet out of design mode in order to activate it.

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi @Dutta here my situation not manually creating the datetime in Excel Sheet. I have code in C# in the application. So From that code only i am plotting the Dropdown and values for that dropdown. Likewise I need to get the DateTimePicker also

Comment: Oo I see. Could you please share the C# code. Although I dont think we can add an Active X from the code and further we have to drill down to so many options and enabling the developer tab also is pretty hectic.

Comment: For DateTime I didnt write and C#

Comment: Alright. I will try to work on it. If there is any solution for it. I will post it.